# Can you help me troubleshoot a DeLonghi BAR32?

Tags: espresso, ground-coffee, espresso-machine

The problem is when I put coffee grounds in, it drips very slowly, it used to come out as a stream.

- water comes out with the coffee holder off
- water comes out with the coffee holder on with no coffee in it
- I am using the same coffee I always use with the same ground

Here are the things I have tried:

1. descaled
2. unscrewed the metal filter on the machine and cleaned it
3. took apart the filters on the coffee holders and cleaned them

Comment: What kind of filter baskets does the portafilter come with? Is it a regular basket or is it one that only has only a few real holes in the middle? How many grams is the basket rated for and how much are you using?

Comment: This seems like the o-ring for water resistance is displaced. Did you check it?